I am automating flutter based android app using selenium java. App gets so slow on some pages that I have to wait 25-30 seconds to click on any thing
I am automating a Flutter-based Android app using Selenium Java. The app gets so slow on some pages that I have to wait 25-30 seconds to click on anything or any interaction. I have disabled the animations as well but does not work for me.
To stop animation I have used
driver = new AndroidDriver(serviceBuilder.getUrl(), options);
        driver.executeScript("mobile: shell",ImmutableMap.of("command", "settings put global window_animation_scale 0"));
driver.executeScript("mobile: shell",ImmutableMap.of("command", "settings put global transition_animation_scale 0"));
driver.executeScript("mobile: shell",ImmutableMap.of("command", "settings put global animator_duration_scale 0"));


Please comment here. This blocks me to automate my application
